# What is the Mathematica equivalent for the Excel function tinv()?

Tags: functions, probability-or-statistics

> `TINV()` returns the t-value of the Student's t-distribution as a function of the probability and the degrees of freedom. For example `TINV(0.475,42) = 0.720842172`.
>   ([source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/tinv-HP005209317.aspx))

What is the Mathematica equivalent for the Excel function tinv()?

Comment: Technically, there is no exact *Mathematica* equivalent (at least for TINV in older versions of Excel--it may have been improved in the latest version): TINV is flawed and produces ever more erroneous results as the first argument approaches 0 or 1 :-).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Either of `InverseCDF[StudentTDistribution[42], 1 - 0.475/2]` or `InverseSurvivalFunction[StudentTDistribution[42], 0.475/2]` should do the trick, taking into account that you're using the form for two-tailed tests.

Answer (score 11):

`Quantile[StudentTDistribution[42], 1 - 0.475/2]` also works.